# Why is Delegate created with `Delegate.CreateDelegate` faster than lambda and method delegates?

Tags: c#, performance, reflection, lambda, delegates

All this time I've been reading about reflection, everybody is always saying: "reflection is slow", "reflection is slow".

Now I decided to test how slow, and for my surprise, a delegate created with reflection is actually about twice as fast as a delegate created with lambda, and, also surprisingly, about four times faster than delegates taking declared methods.

**See the code**

This is a custom class whose property get method will be used in the delegates:

```c#
#class to test
class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass A { get; set; } //property to be gotten
    public static SomeClass GetA(SomeClass c) { return c.A; } //declared getter method
}
```

These are the three delegates I tested:

```c#
PropertyInfo AProp = typeof(SomeClass).GetProperty("A");

//1 - Created with reflection
Func<SomeClass, SomeClass> Getter = (Func<SomeClass, SomeClass>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<SomeClass, SomeClass>), null, AProp.GetGetMethod());

//2 - Created with a lambda expression
Func<SomeClass, SomeClass> Getter2 = c => c.A;

//3 - Created from a declared method
Func<SomeClass, SomeClass> Getter3 = SomeClass.GetA;
```

These are the tests:

```c#
SomeClass C = new SomeClass();
C.A = new SomeClass(); //test doesn't change whether A is set or null
Stopwatch w;

//reflection delegate
w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { SomeClass b = Getter(C); }
w.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);

//lambda delegate
w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { SomeClass b = Getter2(C); }
w.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);

//method delegate
w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { SomeClass b = Getter3(C); }
w.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);

//no delegate
w = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) { SomeClass b = C.A; }
w.Stop(); Console.WriteLine(w.Elapsed);
```

**And the results:**

[image]

I also tried inverting the test order, to see if there was an influence, or if the watches were tricking me somehow, but no, tests are consistent.

**EDIT:** considering the "release" compilation, as suggested:

[image]

Now... I would have expected lambda to be slower

Comment: I don't see much of a difference between the lambda and reflection performance when compiled in release mode, but I do see a similar output to yours in debug mode.

Comment: ... of course .... that hadn't crossed my mind. You may post that as an answer if you like.

Comment: I can't actually say what the reason is, and where is the error, but here are my [results](https://i.imgur.com/WoaAdmw.png) for this code made with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org)   library. Benchmarking is hard for sure.

Comment: For doing this kind of benchmark I suggest you use BenchMarkDotNet, it can give you a lot more insight into the reason why you are seeing this sort of behavior such as allocations, memory usage, GC pauses etc https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet

Comment: Have you seen this? http://vibrantcode.com/2013/02/19/lambdas-vs-method-groups/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the decompile of that:

```
    Func<SomeClass, SomeClass> Getter = (Func<SomeClass, SomeClass>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<SomeClass, SomeClass>), null, AProp.GetGetMethod());
    Func<SomeClass, SomeClass> arg_51_0;
    if ((arg_51_0 = Program.<>c.<>9__12_0) == null)
    {
        arg_51_0 = (Program.<>c.<>9__12_0 = new Func<SomeClass, SomeClass>(Program.<>c.<>9.<Main>b__12_0));
    }
    Func<SomeClass, SomeClass> Getter2 = arg_51_0;
    Func<SomeClass, SomeClass> Getter3 = new Func<SomeClass, SomeClass>(SomeClass.GetA);
```

Notice the first survives the compiler almost unchanged, while the second the third are pretty heavily modified.

If I had to hazard a guess:

The first call is taking advance of some kind of sneaky memory management C++/COM tricks used in the Delegate library.

The second is creating a new method and adding a null check before calling it's new method.

While the third is doing something similar to the second but is saving that until runtime, which is my guess as to why still a property call within a new inline method (which I would have expected to get put out into its own compiler created method, similar to the second version, so I'm guessing that part is going to happen at compile time, which would explain why it's time is so ridiculously higher than the first two).

I think the comments around reflection being slow are more targeted to large libraries; and I'd guess you're not seeing it here because the reflected on class, is extremely small, so there's not a lot to reflect over.

EDIT: As I was typing up that last bit I decided to try and slow down the first call by expanding the SomeClass object. I added about 30 new properties and 20 or so new methods. Didn't seem to make a difference. I've heard all the warnings on reflection too, so this is a bit surprising. [This](http://mattwarren.org/2016/12/14/Why-is-Reflection-slow/) post points out there's a cache involved with all this that is probably helping a lot to. If all the method meta data is cached then reflections should be faster than going through the extra methods and checks added by the compiler. Maybe it comes in when you're reflecting over an external class, that's not already loaded/cached. That's a significantly more involved experiment though.